# Multiplicity and continuity issues for infinite knot vector of Bspline

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, bezier-curve, spline

I want to investigate the continuity issues at different knot which is given as a sequence of (infinite) knot vector $\tau = (0,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,...)$.

What is the multiplicity of above knots? how to investigate the continuity issues if we consider the degree of these basis functions is 2?

Answer (score 1):

Multiplicity is for knot value, not for the entire knot vector. So, the knot values $0, 1, 3, 4, 5$ and 6 all have multiplicity 1 while knot value $2$ has multiplicity $2$. In general, the continuity at a knot value is (degree - multiplicity). Therefore, the continuity at $t=2$ is only $C^0$ when degree is 2. However, for a B-spline curve of degree 2 with such a knot vector, the valid parameter range starts at $t=2$, which means that $C(t=2)$ is the start point of this curve. Therefore, this B-spline curve will still be $C^1$ continuous unless there are more knots of multiplicity = 2 after knot value $6$.